# 400: BadRequest on upload

Tags: google-drive-api

We sometimes get a `BadRequest` on `insert` requests. There's nothing wrong with the posted body values but what I notice is that it happens when creating a file with a newly created parent. Is it possible that because the time between creating the parent folder and inserting a new file inside it is very small that changes my haven't propagated yet and would cause the insert to fail and get a `BadRequest` error? If yes, what are the other reasons a `BadRequest` may be raised? It's such a generic name that I don't believe it's just for invalid parent errors. I was expecting a `404` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a 400 Bad Request, the response will also contain a descriptive error message  that tells you why the request is invalid.

For some other Google Drive specific errors, check the page at https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors

Answer (score 0):

We encounter the following but cant find documentation for generic 400.

```
400 Bad Request
```

{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}